# how to set vim autoclose bracket without blank?

Tags: vim

I'm using gvim7.3 on windows7.
When I type "[" or "(" or "{" vim will autoclose them like: "[ | ]" "( | )" "{ | }", "|" is the cursor position.
But I want it autoclose without blanks like: "[|]" "(|)" "{|}", how to set the vim to do this?
Thanks.

Comment: What plugin are you using to autoclose?  autoclose.vim has never had this behavior for me. Braces are always closed without blanks. http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1849

Comment: Hey, I'd like to know that too. I'm looking for such autoclose plugin, because I like when there is space between brackets :)

Answer (score 1):

[AutoClose.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1849) will close braces without putting spaces around the cursor.

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
imap [ []<LEFT>
imap ( ()<LEFT>
imap { {}<LEFT>
imap < <><LEFT>
```

in vimrc. But make sure that there's no spaces after these strings like

```
imap [ []<LEFT>_
```

It makes Vim insert additional spaces between brackets.